# i am facing issue when i run flutter web on chrome it stop on loading

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am facing an issue when I run flutter web on chrome it stops just loading
apps working fine web also build but issue when I run on the browser it shows error

you can see this image [image]

Comment: Please attach the image as it now showing any image attached

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ZPB.jpg

Comment: Please share error as well

Comment: brother no error show execute successful just not show front in web just loading

Comment: Do u use api call on the page ?

Comment: let me show you code of index

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the application you are trying to load is this one;
https://github.com/DhiaOmri/Flutter-eFood-App and it has dependencies like Firebase where you have to attach your own accounts and generate your own services just like he did here; https://github.com/DhiaOmri/Flutter-eFood-App/blob/main/android/app/google-services.json

But for us to understand the issue better you have to provide the complete debug console messages.